# Bottom menu in Twitter bootstrap 3 with some full width container and some normal containers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build the layout asked by our designer using Bootstrap. The layout is something like this:

[image: layout wireframe]

There are two bars that uses the full browser width. The main container and the footer menu uses the fixed container.

I managed to reproduce this layout (and the layouts to smaller screens) using the code bellow, but the problem happens when the screen doesn't have enough height to fit the main container and the footer menu. In this case, the menu falls over the main container.

What am I doing wrong and how could I make the footer menu overflow the screen only when the main container don't have enough vertical space?

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!-- Top decorative bar 3 pixels -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row header-full"></div>
</div>
<!-- Page content vertically centered -->
<div class="container main-container">
    <div class="main-container-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 logo">
                <img src="images/logo-home.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 search-row">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search term" name="search" id="search" value="" aria-describedby="helpBlock" />
                            <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">(Ex.: Lorem ipsum)</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1 options-row-search">
                                <a href=""class="btn btn-default btn-sm search-kind">Option A</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-lg-3 options-row-search">
                                <a href=""class="btn btn-default btn-sm search-kind">Option B</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-4 col-lg-3 options-row-search">
                                <a href=""class="btn btn-default btn-sm search-kind">Option C</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg other-search dropdown">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-toggle button-text" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Other Search <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Option A</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option B</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Option C</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default search">Search</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- footer decorative bar 6 pixels -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row footer-full"></div>
</div>
<!-- footer menu -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row footer">
        <div class="col-xs-12 footer-links-wrapper">
            <a class="footer-link" href="">About us</a> |
            <a class="footer-link" href="">Colaborate</a> |
            <a class="footer-link" href="">FAQ</a> |
            <a class="footer-link" href="">Curiosity</a>   |
            <a class="footer-link" href="">Blog</a>   |
            <a class="footer-link" href="">Contact</a>   |
            <div class="footer-link"><img src="images/dummy-facebook.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS (I removed the xs, sm and md media queries to simplify):

```
.header-full, .footer-full{
    background-color: #318fbc;
}

.main-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.main-container-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.footer, .footer a{
    color: #a9a9b5;
}

#search{
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    color: #a9a9af;
}

.search, .search-kind{
    background: #2496c4;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #1c85b6;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.search:hover, .search-kind:hover{
    background: #1c85b6;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #858585;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.footer-links-wrapper{
    text-align: center;
}

.footer-link{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.options-row-search{
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown button{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    text-align: left;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown button .buttontext{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-shadow: none;
}

.dropdown button .caret{
    position: absolute;
    right: 7px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -2px;
    color: #777;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid #777;
}

.dropdown-menu{
    max-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.help-block{
    font-size: 0.812em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    color: #aaa;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* lg */
@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .header-full{
        height: 3px;
    }

    .footer-full{
        height: 6px;
    }

    .main-container{
        margin-top: -3px;
        margin-bottom: -61px;
    }

    .main-container-wrapper{
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -136px;
    }

    .footer{
        height: 52px;
        line-height: 52px;
    }

    .footer, .footer a{
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    .logo{
        margin-bottom: 2em;
    }

    #search{
        font-size: 20px;
        height: 50px;
    }

    .search{
        width: 120px;
        height: 50px;
        font-size: 20px;
        line-height: 50px;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .search-kind{
        width: 124px;
        height: 28px;
        font-size: 13px;
        line-height: 28px;
        padding: 0;
        margin-top: 1em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

*** UPDATE ***
I forgot to say that the footer menu must be at the bottom of the page even if the content is too short. When the contente is bigger, it can follow the end of content.

Here what I have today (real screenshot removing client information). The two decorative bars are the blue ones.

[image: actual screenshot]

And here's the problem when the window height is too small.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the main content is a fixed width, the whole area needs to be contained within a wrapper. This means your footer menu, would also be inside that wrapper, and not laying outside of it.

Bootstrap 3 has a fixed layout, so why not use it? It allows you to still use rows and cols, and is responsive.

Mockup Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/df00zXUlI7

Based off my understanding of your question, this is pretty darn close to what you are looking for. It is fixed layout, responsive, and using bootstrap and not hacks.

You were using the fixed layout, but looking at your image, you don't have to use the fixed layout version of Bootstrap. The fixed layout is for sites that do not take up the full page and are a fixed width. The whole site is in a div container, 960px wide centered on the page. What you are doing, is creating a page that looks like Google. So you can use 100% width, and just center your content, and no borders, and achieve the same result. Either way is fine, but just stating for your case, it doesn't have to be fixed.

For your footer nav, use Bootstrap's sticky footer. No need for custom CSS hacks when Bootstrap comes with what we need. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/ use that and it will create your bottom nav. Of course, you will have to center the content inside it to match your mockup.

For the top blue bar, it could be attached to the body{} style or the first 100% wrapper your using. For the bottom blue bar, it could be a top border on the sticky footer. There isn't really a need to create a blue div to pull this off. The best bet would to use CSS (a border, background image, gradient,etc) to pull it off.

For example, to add the blue to the bottom footer CSS for the Bootstrap sticky footer:

```
footer { border-top: 2px solid blue; }
```

In your custom style.css file, you can define already defined rules (defined by bootstrap) to override the CSS, or add to it. The sticky nav doesnt have a border, so adding the footer CSS above to your own stylesheet would add a blue border 2 pixels wide to the top of your footer sticky nav.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question adding the constraint that I forgot to mention. I edited your bootply to remove the extra content and the footer menu doesn't stays at the bottom of the page. Here's the forked bootply http://www.bootply.com/9o8ShrDIkS

Comment: Have you seen this: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/  - Bootstrap has sticky footer too :) Also, what are the thin blue bars across the top and bottom? are they like an HR, just a visual line for design?

Comment: This link you sent seems to be what I was looking for. I'll try it and if it is the answer, please edit your answer to be accepted as the correct anwser. I'll comment as soon I can test it. About the blue bars, they are just a visual line for design.

Comment: Thanks for this link and the border suggestions. It works perfectly.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it worked out. Thanks for coming back and selecting an answer :)